# What are the Best ways to handle angular errors to prevent showing broken bindings on page?

Tags: angularjs, error-handling

If my Get $http service fails for any reason, example server returns 500, then I see all my bindings on the page, and the page is broken.

I am Wondering what people are doing to handle such situations?

I was thinking to redirect to some error page.

Thanks

Comment: Not at all clear what your issue is without a [mcve]. Also please read [ask]

Comment: you can use `promises` and do what ever you want http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/

Comment: Ok I thought the question didnt require code to understand but here you go: You have a Get Call  $http.get(url).then(success,fail).catch(something); now If it fails, I can log it etc. but page still shows with broken bindings {{Broken Binding}} .. So I guess my Q is What are you guys doing in these cases. You cant show a broken page, so what methods are you guys using?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-bind` instead of `{{}}` for bindings which you expect can be broken because of no response from server

Comment: Yes, using ng-bind, but in some cases its not possible to always use ng-bind. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: What cases specifically? Also it would be more helpful if you create a plunkr to reproduce the issue

Comment: In cases where there is more stuff going on, I cant always introduce an element and use ng-bind, its not always practical.

Comment: yeah. But you should be specific in your question mentioning those exact scenarios. Without code for your html bindings, it will be difficult to tell a solution

Comment: Even if you do use ng-bind the page will still be broken, having empty tags all over the place.

Comment: This is a process scenario, I don't see what code will help you understand. I think the question is really clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can do:

1. Ng Cloak, but that doesn't always work on complex pages.
2. Redirect to an error page, and Log the error using log service.

Any others please mention.